# Remove JSON row columns without looping

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I have an API that returns JSON data. But now I want to remove some of the data without looping through the entire object.

The sample JSON data is:

```
[
{
"cost":"KES 0.8000",
"messageId":"ATXid_0fae395279b54d51519de5581230a7e8",
"messageParts":1,
"number":"+2547112xxxxxx",
"status":"Success",
"statusCode":101
},
{
"cost":"KES 0.8000",
"messageId":"ATXid_19a0a09efcf39e87245a57f6403631d5",
"messageParts":1,
"number":"+2547112xxxxxx",
"status":"Success",
"statusCode":101
},
{
"cost":"0",
"messageId":"None",
"number":"+25470000000000",
"status":"InvalidPhoneNumber",
"statusCode":403
}
]
```

I want to extract only data like:

```
[
{
"number":"+2547112xxxxxx",
"status":"Success"
},
{
"number":"+2547112xxxxxx",
"status":"Success"
},
{
"number":"+25470000000000",
"status":"InvalidPhoneNumber"
}
]
```

I am working using Node.js with express framework.

Comment: not possible to do what you want without looping. Either you will do it manually or will use an method with an internal iterator (map, filter, reduce, etc). Either way, looping is necessary.

Comment: what does it mean? "without looping through the entire object."
you don't want to us array.map ?

Comment: What's more important - 1. removing the data or 2. not looping? Why not just keep the data you don't need - thereby avoid the loop. Are you sure this is not an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: If you manually loop through the object, I guess it will take more time.

Comment: @AlbertAlberto Have a nice day.

Comment: Right - there is always a trade off between time consumption and memory consumption. You are putting weight on the time consumption when that may not even be the right problem to solve. Besides, as a point of trivia, it has been proven over and over that the traditional `for()` loop is the _fastest_ way to loop over data

Comment: @RandyCasburn Out of curiosity, do you say `for()` is better than `map()`?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - Better is subjective - it is certainly faster for any size dataset. In a professional environment I always prefer map because I don't have to write unit tests for my loops! :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks, that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple ways, using the `.map()` function, you can do something like this:

```js
console.log(arr.map(({number, status}) => ({
  number,
  status
})));
```

**Full Snippet**

```js
const arr = [{
    "cost": "KES 0.8000",
    "messageId": "ATXid_0fae395279b54d51519de5581230a7e8",
    "messageParts": 1,
    "number": "+2547112xxxxxx",
    "status": "Success",
    "statusCode": 101
  },
  {
    "cost": "KES 0.8000",
    "messageId": "ATXid_19a0a09efcf39e87245a57f6403631d5",
    "messageParts": 1,
    "number": "+2547112xxxxxx",
    "status": "Success",
    "statusCode": 101
  },
  {
    "cost": "0",
    "messageId": "None",
    "number": "+25470000000000",
    "status": "InvalidPhoneNumber",
    "statusCode": 403
  }
];
console.log(arr.map(({number, status}) => ({
  number,
  status
})));
```

Comment: That still "loops over the entire array". OP's question was about NOT using a loop.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yea, I get it. Sometimes these questions look for not using `for ( ... )` or `while { ... }` but using built-in functions.

Comment: Makes sense - I realize I am being quite literal. That's why I'm asking the clarifying questions. Your solution is obvious - perhaps the OP could benefit from the explanation of why the internal iterators are beneficial?